# Is there a limit or something on json fie size or array length or a limit concerning this on the server side?

Tags: php, javascript, json, post, web

I use a js function to call php to write a large json into a file.
js here:

```
function createJson(jsonname){
    $.post("function/create_json.php", jsonname);
}
```

my json is structured like this:

```
var info = {
    info: {},
    para: [
    ],
};
```

I use a for loop to add data into it like:

```
info.para.push({height: h});
```

and the php to create json file using data that createJson pass to it

```
<?php

$json = $_POST;
$json_encoded = json_encode($json);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_encoded);
$file_path = $json_decoded->info->file_path;
$fore_path = data_file_path();

file_put_contents($fore_path . $file_path, $json_encoded);

?>
```

The problem is there seems to be some kind of limit. The length of para array in the json is about 996. I checked info.para[1000].data before I call createJson and it returned the correct value, but when the json is created, it only has 996 members in para. so I guess the problem is on the php side, and I checked the setting in php.ini the post_max_size is set to 8M, and the json it creates is about 15KB. Now I'm confused and don't know where the problem is, does anybody know where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A shot in the dark, pretty much, but could the server be time outing?

Comment: The json file is created as I examined. It's unlikely it timed out.

Comment: do you get a reply from the ajax request (if you inspect the response). Perhaps you are out of memory? And would it not be better to send the filepath as a get parameter, preventing you from having to encode / decode the json, and just write what you get trough POST to a file. Should improve your performance dramatically...